Error al crear un nuevo proyecto en Angular17
Quiero crear un nuevo proyecto en Angular, pero me manda las siguientes lineas de error:
Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-tutorial@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"18.0.0" from @angular/animations@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/david/.npm/_logs/2024-05-25T08_29_56_733Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/david/.npm/_logs/2024-05-25T08_29_56_733Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Tengo la version más nueva de node y npm, pero simplemente no puedo crear ningun proyecto nuevo.

Creo que esto te puede ayudar First Steps with Angular: Triumphing Over Installation Troubles | by Heshan (George) Qiu | Medium

Actualiza la pregunta con la version de node, sistema operativo y package.json. Es un muy dificil poder darte guía sin esa info

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas. La que respuesta que me ayudó fue la de @René. Tuve que hacer un borrado forzoso de caché y fue así como ya pude usar sin problemas todos los comandos de Angular. Gracias a todos por su apoyo.

@ZePekenho puedes responder la pregunta con lo que hiciste y marcarla como resuelta.
